# Multi level GROUP BY clause not allowed

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following CrossTab query

```
TRANSFORM Max(VWDRSSTA.DATUM_ZEIT) AS MaxOfDATUM_ZEIT
SELECT VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
,IIF(VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = 'VS', (
        SELECT (Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL)) AS d
        FROM VWDRSSTA
        ), NULL) AS Dunkel
,Max(VWDRSSTA.VERS_NR_INT) AS Versicherungsnummer
 FROM VWDRSSTA
 INNER JOIN V_NAMES ON (VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = V_NAMES.SYSTEM_CODE)
AND (VWDRSSTA.EREIGNIS = V_NAMES.EREIGNIS)
GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
ORDER BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
PIVOT V_NAMES.MAPPED_NAME;
```

which gives me the error "Multi-level GROUP BY clause is not allowed in a subquery". Where am I going wrong with the code?

Comment: instead of Select max(vwdrssta.dunkel) can you try DMax("dunkel", "vwdrssta") ?

Comment: I tried with DMax("DUNKEL","VWDRSSTA","SYSTEM ='VS'") AS Dunk and it runs but It gives me the Value 1 for all the records. Actually the field Dunkel has only 0 or 1 in it. The corresponding field has VS and ZW. I only want the maximum value for VS for all the antragnummers. So it should be both 0's and 1's.

Comment: Dmax solved your initial question?, I do not understand your second question. If you are looking a max VS value for "each" antragsnummer, you should do Dmax("VS", "VWDRSSTA", "[ANTRAGSNUMMER]=outer_vwdrssta.ANTRAGSNUMMER"). change your **from vwdrssta** to from vwdssta as outer_vwdrssta

Comment: dmax returns the highest value, it can't return both 0 and 1 and as I said I do not understand your scenario. maybe rephrase your question with evidence/possible outputs!

Comment: I rephrased my question. Let me know if it was clear.

Comment: Please do not merge two questions. Ask them separately. Has your "multi level group by" question solved by using DMax? if so, please place a secondary question to achieve the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yes the Multilevel group was solved but it did not give me the desired result which I have updated in my question.

Comment: Another person who has same issue as you might get confused reading your title/post and the answers. Hence merging questions is not a good idea. Leave the original question as it is and place a new question. That would help everyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126741/discussion-between-ashwin-and-krish-km).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

It should do the trick.

---

Edit to detail my answer :

```
TRANSFORM Max(VWDRSSTA.DATUM_ZEIT) AS MaxOfDATUM_ZEIT
SELECT VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
    ,IIF(VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = 'VS', (
            SELECT (Max(VWDRSSTA.DUNKEL)) AS d
            FROM VWDRSSTA
            ), NULL) AS Dunkel
    ,Max(VWDRSSTA.VERS_NR_INT) AS Versicherungsnummer
FROM VWDRSSTA
INNER JOIN V_NAMES ON (VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM = V_NAMES.SYSTEM_CODE)
    AND (VWDRSSTA.EREIGNIS = V_NAMES.EREIGNIS)
GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER, VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM
ORDER BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER
PIVOT V_NAMES.MAPPED_NAME;
```

Comment: It gives me an error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ANTRAGSNUMMER' as part of an aggregate function".

Comment: Check the edit, my point is there : `GROUP BY VWDRSSTA.ANTRAGSNUMMER, VWDRSSTA.SYSTEM`

Comment: I get the previous error "Multi-level GROUP BY clause is not allowed in a subquery"

Comment: Stuck too. Can't help you further. Sorry guy :(

Answer (score 0):

You cross-tab query contains a secondary "aggregated" SQL and this is not allowed in ACCESS Cross-tab query.

change the `Select max(vwdrssta.dunkel) ... part to  DMax("dunkel", "vwdrssta")` which will get rid of that error message.